# Access Fragment elements from Activity parent in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to implement in a android app a big form that have 4 sections, so i created 01 Activity with 4 fragments using the ViewPager. Each fragment has some EditText fields. On the 4th fragment, i have the Button to finish the form, so i'd like to click on it and get all the EditText fields.

I think the best solution is to get all of these EditText fields on the MainActivity.java , but when i try to access theses elements from any fragment, I get only this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

any idea how to access these elements or any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a shared POJO in the activity, and update it from your Fragment class on every next press.

Read here on how an activity should communicate with fragment
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

As suggested in the docs you may have an interface for each fragment being implemented by the activity, with the final fragment notifying finish using a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a scenario once when creating a survey application.

This is the approach I took:

- Create your fragments as needed.
- As expected, add your first fragment to your activity.
- Important part here - when a user clicks NEXT or Swipes to the next Page, add the answers to a map (each question will map to an answer)
- Now repeat this process until you reach the final fragment and simply read out the values (Questions and Answers) from your map.

I found this easier to achieve and gives the expected outcome!

Good luck and happy coding!